# Unable to give an alias name to a column using "as" in mysql

Tags: mysql, column-alias

Query:

```
Select batch as Senior_PM_Batch from profile where designation = 'project manager' and batch <= ALL(select batch from profile where designation = 'project manager');
```

The query gives the accurate result but is not able to rename the column `batch` to `Senior_PM_Batch`.

Result shows the column name as `Batch` only.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select batch as `Senior_PM_Batch` from profile where designation = 'project manager' and batch <= ALL(select batch from profile where designation = 'project manager');
```